# When and how will charged oscillating pendulum in vacuum and Earth gravity stop?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, oscillators

Let's say there is a positively charged metallic sphere hanging on a thread in Earth's gravity and in vacuum. There is no electric field (except for the field from the sphere itself), no friction etc. The sphere is pushed at the lowest point with a velocity $v_0$ perpendicular to the thread and starts oscillating. When and how will it stop? Does the answer depend on whether the resistance to the current on the sphere is zero or non-zero?

Is it a known problem? I could not find anything like this.

Comment: You'd have to consider all forms of energy loss in the system, as I see it the primary one is electromagnetic radiation due to the oscillation of the charge.